# how to make loop for Johansen cointegration test for multivarite time series and get all possible combinations in Rstudio?

Tags: r, loops, multivariate-testing

I am very new in R and statistics.  I would like to perform the Johansen cointegration test for 75 columns by using a loop. And then to have the result as a data frame or a list sort out trace test and confidence levels 90% 95% 99% into data frame.

I have a time series in format `data.frame`. As I said, 75 columns with different names (company with daily data) and 495 rows.

According to ADF test time series are stationary.

So basically my data looks like:
`Name Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6 Name7 Name8 ... Name75`
(all  names are different)

I know that to get all possible combinations I have to use `combn()`, so I presume that my code should look like:

```
 combn(seq_len(ncol(myData)), 2,
         FUN=function(x) ca.jo(Farm2[, x[1]], Farm2[, x[2]]), simplify=FALSE)
```

Or may be something like :

```
for (col in colnames(myData)) {
  print(col)
  data <- myData[, col]
  print(data)
  Jo <- ca.jo(data, type="trace", K=2, ecdet="none", spec="longrun")
  summary(Jo)
}
```

But nothing is working.

Can someone help me understand and correct my loop?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that critical values are only reported for systems with **less than 11 variables** and are taken from Osterwald-Lenum, maybe you should consider restructuring your input data if you want to use Johansen test for cointegration in `urca` package.

Read more [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/urca/man/ca.jo.html).

Comment: yes i know about less the 11 variables ...but I had that hope somehow to loop full data frame but in the same time to make it according to this "11 rule"